# FinderSync invalidated on El Capitan

Tags: sqlite, mono, findersync

We have an application written in Mono that needs to communicate with an Finder Sync App extension.

All is working fine until we tried our app on El Capitan instead of on Yosemite.

We use a shared SQLite database to tell what paths are in which state and use `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` for communication between the two.

The shared SQLite database is outside of the sandboxed env so we have putted an excepention in our entitlements `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write`

If we remove this exception from the app extension, the extension works (but obviously we can't read our db)

Then we tought of putting the SQLite DB into memory, but shared memory databases isn't possible over multiple processes.

I can't find how I can create a `NSFileHandle` for a Sqlite Connection.

We could send over all the info to the application extension, but then that has to keep it in memory (preferably in a SQLite, cause we need to do some querying.)

Does anyone has some pointers of what we could do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look in [The Application Group Container Directory](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW21) it might do in your case. Basically it allows you to have shared folder between apps/extension.

> App group container directories. A sandboxed app can specify an entitlement that gives it access to one or more app group container directories, each of which is shared among all apps with that entitlement.

After some research on similar problem I found it's much easier to have simple TCP server in main app that responds to extension with file status. This way you can easily broadcast file status change to all extension instances etc.

Comment: Thanks, I have a folder now, but for some reason SQLite isn't allowed to create files there. I can create file with NSFileManager

Comment: It worked by creating a zero byte for SQLite to handle.